# how do i disable javascript while running headless selenium server and using firefox?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

i am using headless selenium server with firefox but selenium is throwing exception while loading JavaScript. Is it possible to ignore JavaScript while running selenium heedlessly.

Answer (score 0):

in case of PhantomJs Headless Tesing you can do it like this

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    // prepare capabilities
    Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(false);//by default it was enabled

    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        "E:\\browsers\\phantomjs-1.8.2-windows\\phantomjs.exe"
    );


    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
   driver.get("https://www.google.com");

}
```

if you want to disable javascript in  firefox programtically in selenium you can do it by creating 
profile

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile .SetPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile );
```

Comment: Have you actually seen this working with PhantomJS?  Disabling javascript in firefox works fine but phantomjs still seems to have javascript enabled.  The logs show that javaScriptEnabled is being passed to PhantomJSDriver as false.

Comment: That will not work. [You can't disable JavaScript for PhantomJS.](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/253#issuecomment-31424044)